# Azure functions / API: How to create a proxy

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-api-management, azure-api-apps

I am trying to create a proxy app that will forward my requests.

I will use it like this (works for some public proxies):

```
var proxy = new WebProxy { Address = new Uri("proxyUrl") };
var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler { Proxy = proxy };
var client = new HttpClient(handler: httpClientHandler, disposeHandler: true);
await client.GetAsync("https://www.whatsmyip.org");
```

I found [this](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/announcing-azure-functions-proxies-in-public-preview/) and [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-proxies) guide by microsoft, however they seem to be outdated, since functions can't have proxies anymore. Hovering over "Proxies" tells me: "This feature is not available for V4-function-apps

[image]

I found [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-versions?tabs=azure-cli%2Cin-process%2Cv4&pivots=programming-language-csharp#runtime), which suggests using API Management instead. So I tried. It looks like this:
[image]

Using the backend configuration on the right, I can forward the request to a specific url if I override the "Service URL":
[image]

But I want to use it as shown in my first code snippet, as a real proxy that works for any endpoint.
Any ideas on that?

Comment: If you want to use a proxy, I would stay away from writing my own implementation. You can either use the Azure Function proxy (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-proxies) but that's not supported on the latest version. Another option is to use YARP (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/shows/on-net/yarp-the-net-reverse-proxy)

Answer (score 0):

There is/was a feature called Azure Functions Proxy. This was used to redirect/modify request. However, even if this feature is gone now, it doesn't mean you can't implement something which redirects you to another website.

```
[FunctionName(nameof(Redirect))]
public static IActionResult Redirect(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = "redirect")] HttpRequest req,
    ILogger log)
{   
        return new RedirectResult("https://google.com", true);
}
```

If you want just to provide an interface for other API calls, I would recommend APIM. But you should be able to return what ever result you want with Functions also, but you need to implement it completely yourself.

It could look something like this (not tested)

```
[FunctionName(nameof(RemoteAPICall))]
public static IActionResult RemoteAPICall(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = "proxy")] HttpRequest req,
    ILogger log)
{   
    var response = await client.GetAsync("http://www.wtfismyip.com/json");
    return new OkObjectResult(response.Content);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I will try to play around with this. Main goal is indeed to bypass the api limit of some other api, so redirection the calls should work, if headers / authorization are passed along.

Answer (score 0):

For Azure Function V4, you need to:

1. Add EnableProxies to AzureWebJobsFeatureFlags in app settings, for example:
   "AzureWebJobsFeatureFlags": "EnableWorkerIndexing, **EnableProxies**"
2. Add proxies.json at the root of your project, for example:

   ```
   {
   "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/proxies",
   "proxies": {
     "root": {
       "matchCondition": {
         "route": "<your-path>"
       },
       "backendUri": "https://<your>.azurewebsites.net/<function>"
     }
   }
   ```

*NOTES: The "Proxies" will always be greyed out (disabled) on the Azure Portal. Just ignore it!*